# How do I write consecutive numbers?

Tags: nouns, writing, numbers

Today I wrote the sentence:

> The supplied definition defines 24 16-bit words per subframe, and ...

I know the recipient will understand the terminology.  I'm concerned about writing the phrase "24 16-bit words".  It almost reads as "2416-bit words".  The only alternative I can think of is wordy and flows poorly:

> The supplied definition defines 24 words per subframe, each 16 bits wide, and ...

I'm of the mind that "sixteen-bit" is not immediately recognisable, and expressing a quantity, especially of 10 or more, is generally best done in numerals.  Is this the best way to write it or is there a better alternative?

Comment: In informal techinal writing I would just put 24x16-bit.  However I think writing one of the numbers out as words is the clearest and most correct solution.  The "bigger than ten" thing is only a guideline.

Comment: The sentence is fine as it stands. By linking the *16* to the *bit* with a hyphen, you have demonstrated what is connected to what, and forever subordinated the *24* to its correct status as a counter for *words*. *24-bit* is a compound adjective that also modifies *words*. Be not afraid to leave it as is.

Answer (score 5):

It seems fine as written because of the technical context.  Using the term 'word' for 2416 bits would be highly unexpected while a 16-bit word is commonplace.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with writing one of the numbers out in words:

> The supplied definition defines twenty-four 16-bit words per subframe, and ...

Although it's a little clumsy, since numbers like 24 aren't usually written as words, it does help avoid the 2416-bit problem, and I find it easier to read than the alternative you provided.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with user17237 that you should write out one of the words, but I'd go the other way:

> The supplied definition defines 24 sixteen-bit words ...

Or, if you don't mind a change of unit,

> The supplied definition defines 24 two-byte words ...

(It would be nice if you could break up "definition defines" somehow too; perhaps something like *lays out* could replace *defines*.)

Edit:
As another alternative to placate the naysayers, perhaps

> ... defines 24 (16-bit) words ...

would suffice, since the most common bitsize of a word is 16 bits, and you're just reminding them of it?

Comment: While "two-byte words" sounds better, I refer to "12-bit words" a lot more often than "16-bit words", and "one-and-a-half-byte words" is starting to sound like imperial measurements.  :-)  BTW, I don't know where all the downvotes are coming from.  T'wasn't I.

Comment: And I should change it to "The supplied definition specifies".  Thanks!

Comment: If this is for a technical audience, spelling out 16 or, worse, replacing it with *two-byte* will impede understanding.  They'll get it, but you're making them work harder for it, which good technical writing should not do.

Answer (score 0):

The supplied definition defines  24 pieces of 16-bit words  per subframe  , and ...

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative a bit shorter:

> The supplied definition defines 24 words per subframe, 16-bit each.

But "definition defines" is not good, saying the same thing twice. Maybe better:

> The supplied definition of 24 words per subframe, 16-bit each, corresponds [to something]

Or some other verb — you can avoid the final "and".